# Convert a program to a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, variables

For my homework for my Python class, we have to make a function that takes a string S, and creates a nested list (elements must be floats) of the numbers of the string, separated at semicolons. For example, the string:

"3.5 1 9.2 4;2 7 0 15;3 1 8 -2"

should produce the list:

[[3.5, 1.0, 9.2, 4.0], [2.0, 7.0, 0.0, 15.0], [3.0, 1.0, 8.0, -2.0]]

I've finally been able to write the program:

```
S = "3.5 1 9.2 4;2 7 0 15;3 1 8 -2"
i = 0
z = 0
temp_list = []
good_list = []
str_temp = ""


S_temp = S.split(";")

while i < len(S_temp):
    str_temp = S_temp[i]
    temp_list = str_temp.split(" ")
    while z < len(temp_list):
        temp_list[z] = float(temp_list[z])
        z += 1
    z = 0
    good_list.append(temp_list)
    i += 1
```

However, I am now stuck trying to figure out how to convert to a function...

I figured it would be along the lines of:

```
def testfunction(S):
    S_temp = S.split(";")

    while i < len(S_temp):
        str_temp = S_temp[i]
        temp_list = str_temp.split(" ")
        while z < len(temp_list):
            temp_list[z] = float(temp_list[z])
            z += 1
        z = 0
        good_list.append(temp_list)
        i += 1
```

However, when I save it and try to run testfunction(S) (after assigning S to be the same string as my original program), I get the following error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment

What is going on here? I am not asking for a direct answer, rather just a hint or two so that I can figure it out and learn from this..

Thanks.

Comment: where is `i=0` in your function ?

Comment: You didn't put the variable initializations into your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing your variables before you use them. It's the same case for i, good_list, and z

```
def testfunction(S):
    S_temp = S.split(";")
    i=0
    good_list=[]
    while i < len(S_temp):
        str_temp = S_temp[i]
        temp_list = str_temp.split(" ")
        z=0
        while z < len(temp_list):
            temp_list[z] = float(temp_list[z])
            z += 1
        z = 0
        good_list.append(temp_list)
        i += 1
```

Comment: should have been a comment

Comment: @vks I just wanted to show him the code. I though that he can't get me if I just mention it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code because of that you dont specify an initial value for `i`,  you got that error ! 
note that always you need to assignment the variables before referenced !

As a more pythonic way you can do it with [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) :

```
>>> [map(float,n.split()) for n in s.split(';')]]
[[3.5, 1.0, 9.2, 4.0], [2.0, 7.0, 0.0, 15.0], [3.0, 1.0, 8.0, -2.0]]
```

so for create a function you can just pass `s` as its argument :

```
def seperator(s):
 return [map(float,i) for i in [n.split() for n in s.split(';')]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting that error is because you forgot to include `i = 0` in the body of your function; you should also include `z = 0` and initialize `good_list`. Declare these both after your `S_temp` assignment.

You should also use lower case for variable and in Python, you don't need to know the the length of a sequence to iterate over it. So `i` is really not required, neither is `z`.  Finally, you need to return the result.

In the end, your code should like this:

```
def test_function(s):
    good_list = []

    for i in s.split(';'):
        temp_list = [] # empty list
        for z in i.split(" "):
            temp_list.append(float(z))
        good_list.append(temp_list)

    return good_list # you forgot to return the result
```